# What does it mean to .py into python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, window

So I have an assignment, and For a specific section, we are supposed to import a .py file into our program."You will need to import histogram.py into your program."
Does that simply mean to create a new python file and just copy and past whatever is in the histogram.py into the file? 
This part of my assignment is to create a graphical display with the contents in the .py file (which confuses me too) I was reading the chapters from the tb and it states how to create a window, but I havent seen anything about importing.. Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: No, it means you need to import it. If you don't know what that means, you need to read some tutorials on Python, it's a pretty basic part.

Comment: All that is involved is putting import {path}.histogram at the top of your new python file. That way the system will insert the histogram.py file at the top of your file for you. All the code in histogram.py will be available to your new program. Making sure you get the path right is important. The easiest thing to do is to keep both files in the same folder and in that case you can leave out {path}.

Comment: Importing is the process they are referring to. Usually that means putting `import` statements as the first lines in the file, in your instance, that would be `import histogram`. See the documentation for more info [Importing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: The question is getting down-voted because you didn't follow the posting guidelines that you were supposed to read before posting.  You can find this information with a simple browser search, or by searching the official Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules).

Comment: This is how one python script can load another script and use its functions and data. You use an `import` statement such as `import os` and then you can use its functions (e.g., `os.listdir('.')`). This is basic python and you may well served by looking through the [standard python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/getting-started-with-python-language/9222/creating-a-module#t=201611151930503925368

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own python file and simply add

```
import histogram
```

at the top of the file (or lets say in the "import" section).
Yout don't need the .py extension. Make sure the histogram.py file is in the same folder like your created py file.

Comment: I see now. Thank you, I just needed clarification Idk why everyones negatively rating my question lol

Comment: This might be because your question is realy python-basic and it seems like your too sloopy exploring the answer to the question by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the files you need before you try and import them, either downloading them or getting them through pyget. Once you have your files then you need to call them ([2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html))

```
from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar
import Fizz
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is paste the file named histogram.py to your working directory and to use the file on your code just type `import histogram` on the top most line of your main code file then you can use anything(functions and variables) from histogram.py.